# Implementing JDBC implementing JFrame

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jframe

I am needing to create a simple application that takes input from the user and inserts the data into my table in SQL Server. I am currently trying to use `JFrame` but I don't exactly know how to implement Action Events and insert data into the database.

Code:

```
// Class 1
// Helper class extending JFrame class
class NewClass extends JFrame {
  
    // JFrame
    static JFrame f;
  
    // JButton
    static JButton b, b1, b2;
  
    // Label to display text
    static JLabel l;
  
    // Main class
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Creating a new frame to store text field and
        // button
        f = new JFrame("Vet Clinic");
  
        // Creating a label to display text
        l = new JLabel("Viewable Content");
  
        // Creating a new buttons
        b = new JButton("Appointment");
        b1 = new JButton("View Pet History");
        b2 = new JButton("View Appointments");
  
        // Creating a panel to add buttons
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
  
        // Adding buttons and textfield to panel
        // using add() method
        p.add(b);
        p.add(b1);
        p.add(b2);
        p.add(l);
  
        // setbackground of panel
        p.setBackground(Color.red);
  
        // Adding panel to frame
        f.add(p);
  
        // Setting the size of frame
        f.setSize(300, 300);
  
        f.show();
    }
}
```

My JDBC Connection code is:

```
public class JAVACONNECT {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
       String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://*****:1433;databaseName=VetClinic";
       String user = "sa";
       String password = "******";
       try{
           Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
           System.out.println("Connected to Microsoft SQL Server");
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("There's an error");
            e.printStackTrace();   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be best to spend some time learning how to use Swing components before jumping straight into database implementation.
In Swing, you are correct in mentioning ActionListeners, which are implemented like so:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // this can be replaced by a lambda
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // execution code goes here, including jdbc code
    }
});
```

When you click the button, that constitutes an "action" and the behaviour defined in the ActionListener is performed.